# css, float alternative

Tags: html, css

In my web app I have a toolbar, it's a div:

The div has 3 spans. The contents of the 3 spans get filled later.

And the size of the individual spans differ every time.

```
<div>
    <span id="ab1" style="display: inline-block;"></span>
    <span id="ab2" style="display: inline-block;"></span>
    <span id="ab3" style="display: inline-block;"></span>
</div>
```

Now, I want, that span "ab1" should be placed on the left, "ab2" and "ab3" on the right
side on the div.

Is this possibe WITHOUT float right/left?

Comment: You have `display: inline-block;` applied to your spans. With inline-block you can't align inline-treated elements in more than one way. You have to choose between text-align left, right, center or justify. Why don't you want to use floats? It may help finding a solution.

Comment: Make a table? If you mean a different way to do it with css, I don't think there's another possibility.

Comment: You can use Flexbox (http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-flexbox/)

Comment: @CosLu He could use `position: absolute;`.

Comment: You could do something VERY SILLY, add a significant `margin-left` to `#ab2`.

Comment: why don't you want to use fload? if you concern about the div height collapsing, you can fix it easily. I believe float is the best choice in this case.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `position:absolute` and `text-align:right`

**CSS**

```css
div{background:red; text-align:right; position:relative;}
#ab1{position:absolute; left:0; background:yellow;}
#ab2{background:yellow;}
#ab3{background:yellow;}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uyemub/1/edit)**

Comment: This works, but only if `#ab1` is the only item on the left and the alignment doesn't change.

Comment: @kleinfreund i didnt get u

Comment: I don't think it's always the use case that `#ab1` is on the left and `#ab2, #ab3` are on the right. This may change every time he loads the page (he mentions the content of the spans gets added afterwards – dynamically).

Comment: @kleinfreund content gets change but not the position of the divs

Comment: But if the content of ab2 or ab3 are bigger than the available space minus the absolute positioned ab1, ab1 will hide a part of the content underneath it. Also ab2 or ab3 will wrap to a new line.

Answer (score 13):

You can use `display flex` for container and `margin-left: auto` for #ab2.

```
div{
    display: flex;
}
#ab2{
    margin-left: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Add `display:flex` to the parent element and `margin-left:auto` to any child element.
(that child element and all the next child elements float to right)

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

span {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#ab2 {
  margin-left: auto; /* this and the next elements float to right */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="ab1">sometext 1</span>
  <span id="ab2">sometext 2</span>
  <span id="ab3">sometext 3</span>
</div>
```

---

Or to display only one element to a side, add higher order to that element

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  border: 1px solid green;
}

span {
  border: 2px solid red;
}

#ab2 {
  margin-left: auto;
  order: 1; /* this becomes the last element, only this element float to right */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="ab1">sometext 1</span>
  <span id="ab2">sometext 2</span>
  <span id="ab3">sometext 3</span>
</div>
```